# Flex <ul> where each <li> is a box, background color won't take full space

Tags: html, css, html-lists, background-color, listitem

Currently building a list that looks like this.

[image]

I decided to make a flexbox out of it, where every li would be a box. Everything works fine, but the background-color on the odd boxes won't stretch to the left. In fact, they stop just before the bullet elements. Here is a snapshot of what I'm doing and my code.

[image]

CSS:

```
ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

li {
    padding: 10px 0 10px;
    padding-left: .5em;
    color: rgba(250, 250, 250);
}

::marker {
    color: rgba(250, 250, 250);
    font-size: 1em;
    content: '\f522';
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
    font-weight: 700;
}

li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.4);
}

li:nth-child(odd)::marker {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0);
}
```

HTML:

```
                        <ul>
                            <li> 2 </li>
                            <li> 3 </li>
                            <li> 5 </li>
                            <li> 7 </li>
                            <li> 8 </li>
                        </ul>
```

I would also like to maintain the ::marker method if possile. I have seen solutions with the ::before and ::after but it's not quite what I'm looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Here I have used `list-style-position: inside` and `padding-left: 0;` in ul.

you can check below code.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
} 
ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    list-style-position: inside;
    padding-left: 0;
}

li {
    padding: 10px 0 10px;
    padding-left: .5em;
    color: rgba(250, 250, 250);
}

::marker {
    color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 1);
    font-size: 1em;
    content: '\f522';
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
    font-weight: 700;
}

li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: red;
}

li:nth-child(odd)::marker {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <ul>
        <li> 2 </li>
        <li> 3 </li>
        <li> 5 </li>
        <li> 7 </li>
        <li> 8 </li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

but I would suggest you use pseudo-element `before` instead of `:marker` because of `:marker` property not supported safari browser

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker

you can refer below example if you want use pseudo-element.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
} 
ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}

li {
    padding: 10px 0 10px;
    padding-left: .5em;
    color: rgba(250, 250, 250);
}

li::before {
    color: rgba(250, 250, 250);
    font-size: 1em;
    content: '\f522';
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
    font-weight: 700;
}

li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: red;
}

li:nth-child(odd)::before {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <ul>
        <li> 2 </li>
        <li> 3 </li>
        <li> 5 </li>
        <li> 7 </li>
        <li> 8 </li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip I will use that! It works well, but when I use the ::before element, the normal bullet points seem to appear to the left of my new bullet points. When I open dev tools, they show as ::marker?

Comment: (Nevermind solved it by puting list-style-type:none; in my ul{} class. That way it removed all original markers.)

Answer (score 1):

Use before pseudo-element. [Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wc5jth0L/3/)

```
li {
    padding: 10px 0 10px;
    padding-left: .5em;
    
    
    &::before {
      content: "F";
      background-color: #000;
      border-radius: 50%;
      width: 5px;
      height: 5px;
      position: relative;
    }
}
```

Replace `content: "F";` with ur `::marker` code

Answer (score 1):

You can carry on using marker but CSS doesn't accept background styling for markers but we can additionally put a pseudo before element onto the odd li elements which has the same height as the li but is positioned to the left.

This snippet gives it a large width rather than attempt a calculation as only that part within the ul itself will be visible.

Note: this snippet puts the ul into a container simply to give it a background and position it.

```css
.container {
  background-color: rgb(88, 88, 88);
  width: 50vw;
  position: relative;
  left: 20vw;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

li {
  padding: 10px 0 10px;
  padding-left: .5em;
  color: rgba(250, 250, 250);
}

::marker {
  color: rgba(250, 250, 250);
  font-size: 1em;
  content: 'M';
  /* PUT \f522 HERE */
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 700;
}

li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.4);
  position: relative;
}

li:nth-child(odd)::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: -100vw;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.4);
}

li:nth-child(odd)::marker {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li> 2 </li>
    <li> 3 </li>
    <li> 5 </li>
    <li> 7 </li>
    <li> 8 </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```